# How to: WPF EventSetter Handler Code NOT in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, eventsetter, datagridrowheader

I have a WPF DataGrid with RowHeader-Style. My Objective is to add a new row when the RowHeader is clicked.

This works:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=*}" />
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="DataGridRowHeader_Click"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

With handler in code behind:

```
private void DataGridRowHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DependencyObject @object)
    {
        var dataGrid = DependencyObjectHelpers.FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(@object);
        if (dataGrid?.ItemsSource is IList list)
        {
            var type = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var position = list.Add(instance);
            EventHandler handler = null!;
            handler = (s, ea) =>
            {
                if (dataGrid.SelectedIndex != position)
                {
                    dataGrid.SelectedIndex = position;
                    dataGrid.LayoutUpdated -= handler;
                }
            };
            dataGrid.LayoutUpdated += handler;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get this working code out of code behind into something like a markup extension, derived setter, attached property or something else? And NOT into the viewmodel, because the handling method has direct reference to the datagrid.

Thanks for any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: This is code behind of the view. It has nothing to do with a view model.

Comment: View, View Model and Model are abstract components of your application architecture. Because C# is the main language (in your case) all three components can and usually will contain code written in e.g. C#. This means your idea is completely wrong as not all C# code is automatically View Model. Responsibilities of a type define if a type is View, View Model, or Model. `partial` keyword allows to split a class definition across multiple files.

Comment: If you define the `x:Class` directive on a XAML root you can join the XAML file with an associated partial class also known as code-behind. XAML and associated C# code like e.g. event handlers, dependency properties, routed events or routed commands etc. and UI logic are part of the abstract View component. Don't follow the misconception that code-behind is something illegal. That's utter nonsense. For example, you can't write a control without C#. A custom control never has a XAML file. It's pure C# code.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your time and thoughts. So I will leave it as it is now. I wasn't sure whether the current approach is legal and appropriate and perhaps other solutions or ideas are existing.

Comment: If you want to encasulate the code for reuse, put it in the code behind of a derived DataGrid.